# Query regarding SPOJ TOURIST

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, computer-science, tail-recursion

Problem statement :

> A lazy tourist wants to visit as many interesting locations in a city
>   as possible without going one step further than necessary. Starting
>   from his hotel, located in the north-west corner of city, he intends
>   to take a walk to the south-east corner of the city and then walk
>   back. When walking to the south-east corner, he will only walk east or
>   south, and when walking back to the north-west corner, he will only
>   walk north or west. After studying the city map he realizes that the
>   task is not so simple because some areas are blocked. Therefore he has
>   kindly asked you to write a program to solve his problem.
>
> Given the city map (a 2D grid) where the interesting locations and
>   blocked areas are marked, determine the maximum number of interesting
>   locations he can visit. Locations visited twice are only counted once.
>
> Input
>
> The first line in the input contains the number of test cases (at most
>   20). Then follow the cases. Each case starts with a line containing
>   two integers, W and H (2 ≤ W , H ≤ 100), the width and the height of
>   the city map. Then follow H lines, each containing a string with W
>   characters with the following meaning:
>
> ```
>  . Walkable area
>  * Interesting location (also walkable area)
>  # Blocked area
> ```
>
> You may assume that the upper-left corner (start and end point) and
>   lower-right corner (turning point) are walkable, and that a walkable
>   path of length H + W − 2 exists between them.
>
> Output
>
> For each test case, output a line containing a single integer: the
>   maximum number of interesting locations the lazy tourist can visit.
>
> Example
>
> ```
> Input: 
>    2 9 7
> *........
>  .....**#. 
>  ..**...#* 
>  ..####*#. 
>  .*.#*.*#. 
>  ...#**...
> *........ 
> 5 5
>   .*.*.
> *###.
> *.*.* 
>  .###* 
>  .*.*.
> ```
>
> Output: 7 8

My solution :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char path[101][101];
int sz1,sz2;
int solve(int a,int b,int i,int j){
if(a>=sz1||b>=sz2||i>=sz1||j>=sz2){
   return 0;
   }
   int c = 0;
if(path[a][b]=='#'||path[i][j]=='#')
    return -100;
if(path[a][b]=='*'){
    c = 1;
    }
if(path[i][j]=='*'&&a!=i)
    c++;
int x =max(max(solve(a,b+1,i+1,j),solve(a+1,b,i+1,j)),max(solve(a,b+1,i,j+1),solve(a+1,b,i,j+1)));

return x+c;
}

int main()
{
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--){
cin>>sz1>>sz2;

for(int i=0;i<sz1;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<sz2;j++)
        cin>>path[i][j];
}

cout << solve(0,0,0,0) << endl;
}
}
```

I have not yet used memoization as I'm just trying to write a backtrack function . But I'm getting wrong answer for the first test case . The correct answer is 7 but this code prints 10. Whats wrong in this recursive solution ?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: No. I can't figure out why grids are being counted multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should swap sz1 and sz2.

First line of input gives number of columns and number of rows respectively. But you treated them in reverse order.

Comment: Why are grids being counted multiple times ?